Heuristics for constrained maximal volumes in hypercubes as $n \to \infty$
It can be shown that there is a unique maximal surface of revolution with constant positive Gaussian curvature embedded in $[0,1]^3$ with a pair of antipodal points as cone points which attain the supremum of distance $\sqrt{3}$.Consider a surface of revolution $S$ and an embedding $e:S \hookrightarrow X^3$ for $X^3=[0,1]^3$ with points $p,q$ elements of $\partial X^3$ where $\partial X^3=X^3-(0,1)^3$ for $\mathrm {sup}~ \mathrm{dist}(p,q)=\sqrt{3}$.
What is $\rho_{\mathrm{max}}=\mathrm{max} \lbrace \mathrm{vol}(S) \rbrace_{p,q}$ assuming $S$ must remain a surface of revolution and have constant positive Gaussian curvature? In other words, what is the volume of the largest surface of revolution with constant Gaussian curvature that can be embedded in $X^3$ with a pair of antipodal corners as cone points?
The volume of said surface can be numerically found to be just above $1/2$. I'm wondering if there are any heuristical arguments that can shed light on what happens to the sequence of volumes plotted vs the dimension as $n \to \infty$.
In $n$ dimensions the problem reads:
Consider a codimension one surface of revolution $S$ and an embedding $e:S \hookrightarrow X^n$ for $X^n=[0,1]^n$ with points $p,q$ elements of $\partial X^n$ where $\partial X^n=X^n-(0,1)^n$ for $\mathrm {sup}~ \mathrm{dist}_n(p,q)=\sqrt{n}$.

What is $\rho_{\mathrm{max}}=\mathrm{max} \lbrace \mathrm{vol}(S) \rbrace_{p,q}$ assuming $S$ must remain a surface of revolution and have constant positive Gaussian curvature? Plotting the $(n, \rho_n)$ what kind of asymptotics as $n\to \infty$ can we expect?

For all I know the sequence of maximal volumes could behave erratically or could be well behaved. This is why I am looking for possible heuristics to suggest what might be occurring in higher dimensions. I do not need a proof as it is beyond reach. If there is a reframing of the problem or a related problem I'd be interested in resources.
